# Routing VPN traffic through another VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, wireguard

I am testing out the new wireGuard VPN protocol and was wondering if it was possible to rout its traffic through a commercial VPN such as Hotspot Shield or Nord. I have the wireGuard VPN server at home and the client is on my laptop. I was hoping I would be able to connect to say Hotspot Shield and then connect to my home wireGuard Server through the Hostpot VPN with all traffic going through both layers.

e.g. stack would look like: (Hotspot Sheild [wireGuard {Browser Traffic} ] )

Im fairly new to all this so any help would be awesome, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is call VPN Chaining or Double VPN or Doblehop VPN.

There are several ways of achieving it:

- Doublehop VPN
  May be offered by some VPN providers as a static option.
  When you connect to a specific VPN server, your connection is immediately linked
  to another VPN server.
- Configurable multihop VPN client
  This VPN cascading is another option provided by some VPN providers and
  allows configuration from within the VPN client.
- Router Setup + VPN Client
  Here you configure one VPN service on your router, then use a VPN client on
  the computer.
- Browser Extension + VPN Client
  If the VPN provider also has a secure browser proxy, you may connect to a VPN server
  through the client first and then to another one through the browser extension.
- Host Machine + Virtual Machine
  Here you connect to one VPN on the host computer, then connect to another
  on the virtual machine. This requires the VM to use NAT for going through
  the host, rather than Bridge that goes directly through the router.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described, it sounds like you would have the following potentially (depending on routing orders etc):

everything initially routed through Hotspot shield to their endpoint server
From their endpoint server to your wireguard server encryped by wireguard
I am then assuming from your wireguard server over you home internet to the internet unprotected.

This is assuming I have understood your setup.

If you are trying to double encrypt your data, and remain anonymous, so that you appear to be on the hotspot server (not your home one), then the wireguard server you connect to would need to be the one using the connection to hotspot shield.

I hope that is what you are trying to get.

If you are just trying to access your home server, I am not sure of the real added benefit of going via hotspot shield, unless you are trying to hide where you are going from someone on the network you are starting on.  At some point in the internet you will only have the wireguard encryption.

Hope this helps