# How to run two default ubuntu openvpn tunels on the same laptop one inside another?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have one config for OpenVPN tunnel from my initial location to elsewhere in the world. Then I want to run another OpenVPN app to run through the first channel to another place, I already have two configs for both setups, I only need to set up a composition of VPN tunnels. I'm pretty noob at networking and VPNing so detailed explanation and links to the detailed guides will be highly appreciated.

**UPD**

As the question was misunderstood, I'll try to explain a little bit more.
Sorry for my poor ASCII, but looks like the only way to draw graphs in SO.

```
tunnel1  \_________/
tunnel2 \___________________________/
PC------------------------------------- target server
         ___________________________
        / _________                 \ target location
         /         \ interim server
```

But not like that, as it was offered to do in comments:

```
           tunel1                  tunel2                    
        \___________/        \______________/
PC------------------- interim ---------------- target server
         ___________          ______________
        /           \        /              \ target location
```

I have OpenVPN config for `tunnel1` and for `tunnel 2`. Could I start one instance of ubuntu-linux `openvpn` for `tunnel1` config, and then run another instance of the same program with `config#2` in that way it would not notice that it works through instance #1? 
If so what exactly I should do and which changes to the config I should do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Routing VPN traffic through another VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/1529255/routing-vpn-traffic-through-another-vpn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want your traffic to "ricochet" through two VPN tunnels, one after the other, the first connecting your PC to a distant machine, whatever that is, and the second channeling your incoming traffic to another distant location.

Is that so?

If so, it would help to know if the OpenVPN program allows two instances of itself to run concurrently on your PC. If not, but you can change that in the program's settings, then you might find a solution to your problem.

If not, and it can't be changed, then you might want to install another VPN app to handle the second part of your packet trip. Not sure that would be easy, unless you can control the distant machine, and set it up there.

If the distant machine is, say, a server and you have no admin rights there, installing software could also be an issue.

Comment: Could you please elaborate if I can do this with default openvpn for ubuntu linux?

Comment: You are right, I totally misunderstood what you were trying to achieve! Sorry. As for an answer, we're back to my question of whether you can run two instances of OpenVPN concurrently on your PC. If yes, then from what I understand, you're trying to send TWO CONCURRENT sets of packets through two different tunnels to a target server, where they'll be routed to two different other computers/servers? Or have I got it wrong again?

Comment: Sorry. Imagine you have a router configured to route all traffic, for example to a remote server somewhere in Europe(for example). Then you connect your pc to that router, and set up a vpn connection to other server, somewhere in Russia(for example).  Whereas you located in America(for example). So your Trafic goes to russia through Europe. I need to achieve this having only one PC.

Comment: Way I see it (now, clearly, I hope), you could achieve it with a virtual machine on your PC, running any OS you like, so long as OpenVPN can run on it. Send your packets from the host to the guest using OpenVPN1, then set OpenVPN2 on the guest to reach the distant server. VirtualBox would let you do that, provided you set the virtual NIC as a bridged connection. You can try it that way, ping a distant server somewhere (a friend's, maybe) and ask for a traceroute in return. If the public IP he/she gives you is not yours, then you're in the game.